# Encapsulating alarm creation code in a different class than the Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm creating my first Android Notifications app, so I'm very much a beginner. I have a class, Notification.java, that asks the user for the time and date. Using these data, it creates an alarm that is triggered at the specified date and time.
Here is my code for Notification.java

```
public class Notification extends Activity {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private SetAlarm alarm;
private Date date;
private Time time;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    findViewById(R.id.setTime).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAlarmTime();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.setDate).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAlarmDate();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.checkBox).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createAlarm();
        }
    });
}

private void setAlarmTime() {

}

private void setAlarmDate() {

}

private void createAlarm() {
    alarm = new SetAlarm();
}
```

}

The createAlarm() method is supposed to actually create the alarm using the information that the user has provided (i.e. time and date). However, I understand that I need the following code block to create the alarm?

```
 private void setTheAlarm() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(SetAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SetAlarm.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval;

    /* Set the alarm to the date specified by user */


    /* Repeating on every x minutes interval */
}
```

However, the Notification.java is where I am extending 'Activity'. It is also where I have the 'pendingIntent; code.

So essentially, how can I move the alarm creation code into a separate class when the code dealing with the Activity is in an entirely different class?

Thanks for the help. I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Why the down votes for this question, without any observation about what should be improved?

Comment: Don´t think about, this happens here in 80%, no explanation, no comment...

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly clear if that is what you want, but if I understand you correct, you need the alarmManager inside an extra class to reach it from everywhere? You could make a static one like this:

```
public class MyAlarmManager{

private static AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
private static PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

//start alarm
public static void setAlarm(Context context, int alarmId, long alarmTime) {

   if (mAlarmManager== null) {
    mAlarmManager= (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   }

Intent startAlarmIntent = new Intent(context, YouReceiver.class);

   if(mPendingIntent==null){

    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, 
startAlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   }

//check the version because of doze mode since MM
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                     mAlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
alarmTime, mPendingIntent);

   } else {
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, alarmTime, mPendingIntent);

   }

}

//stop alarm
public static void stopAlarm(Context context, int id) {

 if (mAlarmManager == null) {
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

  Intent stopAlarmIntent = new Intent(context, YourReceiver.class);

    if(mPendingIntent==null){
    mPendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, stopAlarmIntent, 0);
    }

  mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);
  mPendingIntent.cancel();

  }
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
 MyAlarmManager.setAlarm(this, id, interval);
```

and stop it:

```
 MyAlarmManager.stopAlarm(this, id);
```

You can do this from every class by passing the `context` and the identical `id` . The alarm id must be the same as you passed by starting the alarm, otherwise it will not work. Notice that above MarshMallow, there are some changes for AlarmManager and it´s possible that it does not work in every case. If your app get´s killed or goes into idle mode, the alarm won´t be triggered in every circumstance. To handle doze mode, see this:https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

And be aware of any third party app and battery managers, that could kill your app. Also, Huawei devices have their own battery management besides the doze mode.

If this is not what you wanted, come back. Can´t guarantee that there is no error because I have overseen something, it´s from scratch.